# Framer Motion overwrites inline styles when using variant. Is there a way for it to keep the properties that have been set using the style attribute?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I have a project using Framer Motion to animate in a parent elements and some elements using `whileInView` and `staggerChildren`.

I am using Tailwind CSS to style these elements, but I need to dynamically set the margin on some of them. Tailwind doesn't support dynamic values, so I moved my margin properties to the inline `style` attribute as suggested in the Tailwind documentation.

The issue is that the style atribute is overwritten by Framer Motion when it finishes animating. (My dynamically calculated margins have nothing to do with the animation - the animation is only modifying the opacity.)

**Example code:**

```
    const div1 = {
      hidden: { opacity: 0 },
      show: {
        opacity: 1,
        transition: {
          delay: 1,
          staggerChildren: 1.5
        }
      }
    }
    
    const item = {
      hidden: { opacity: 0 },
      show: { opacity: 1 }
    }
    
    ...
    
    <motion.div
      ref={middleDiv}
      variants={middleText}
      initial="hidden"
      whileInView="show"
      viewport={{ once: true }}>
      <motion.div
        className='flex relative w-full'
        style={{ marginRight: dynamicMarginCalculation}}
        variants={item}
      >
        {/* child elements */}
      </motion.div>
    </motion.div>
```

The dynamic margin is calculated correctly until I scroll the element into view and Framer Motion does the `opacity` animation. When it's done it replaces my `style={{...}}` with just `style="opacity : 1"`, causing the margin to disappear.

Is there a way to get Framer to add its properties to the inline `style` attribute rather than overwriting it?

Thanks for your time

Comment: You can't construct class names dynamically, but [you can add them dynamically, as long as you always use complete class names](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names). That would likely solve your problem, but I didn't test it.

Comment: Unless specified, Framer should not replace properties in `style` at least in my experience. Any chances there could be other factors outside of the posted snippet that could result in `margin-right` not taking effect?

Comment: @JohnLi Okay, I thought it should work that way but wasn't sure. I'll isolate the snippet and test it to see if it works on its own, in case something else is effecting it. Thanks for the info.